# Installed dependency using npm but not working

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, mern

I have installed the following dependencies for my project:

dotenv
cors
express
mongodb
nodemon

But when I try to run the command "nodemon server", it throws the error: "The term 'nodemon' is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program."

I have tried installing it as --save-dev and also, tried updating the scripts in package.json, to have {"serve": "nodemon server.js"} and while the program starts running, the output never shows, which means, neither MongoDB throws connection error, nor does it successfully connect.

**Question**: Please let me know why the dependencies are not working and how to fix it for future uses as well.

Comment: If the *"program starts running"* but has not output this is a problem of your program and not of nodemon. Try adding some output immediately at the start of your program and check if that is shown

Comment: The dependencies are working fine (from what can be told from your very limited information) But like it's written in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon): *"With a local installation, nodemon will not be available in your system path or you can't use it directly from the command line."*

Comment: The program is working now, it wasn't working because npm's path wasn't set in my PC.